# openssl : EVP libraries : error : undefined reference to `EVP_bf_cbc'

Tags: openssl

gcc compiler giving me error as

**undefined reference to `EVP_bf_cbc'**

I user command to compile as **gcc -o CSHARE main.c**

main.c includes call of function **EVP_bf_cbc()**.
I have included openssl/evp.h

How can I link to the library where function like **EVP_bf_cbc()** is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to tell it which libs to link using '-l', like this

`gcc -lssl -lcrypto -o CSHARE main.c`

I think you might need both '-lssl' and '-lcrypto', not sure.

Colum